# Почему выходит ошибка что файла не существует, хотя он находится в той же папке что и java файл, как это исправить?

Tags: java

Почему выходит ошибка что файла не существует, хотя он находится в той же папке что и java файл, как это исправить?

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("Test.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BuferedReader(file);
```

Comment: Потому что приложение ищет файл там откуда было запущено приложение.

Comment: дак оно же запущенно из той же папки

Comment: И тем не менее. Текущий каталог может быть выставлен и не тот, в котором лежит само приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Можете запустить такой метод, и посмотреть откуда считывается файл

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Файл должен находиться в папке проекта, а не там, где джава файл